# Why won't my conjugate gradient algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I made this simple Conjugate Algorithm on Matlab

n = length(b);

r0 = b - A*x0;

p0=r0;

k=1;

n0=(r0')*r0;
while n0 >= eps && k <= n

```
interm = A*p0;

alpha = n0/((p0')*interm);

x0=x0+alpha*p0;

r0=r0-alpha*interm;

n1=(r0')*r0;

if n1 <=eps

    y=x0;

    break

end
betta = n1/n0;

p0=r0+betta*p0;

k=k+1;

n0=n1;
```

end

I checked it dozen of times and saw through  a couple of sources but couldn't find any mistake, and either way it doesn't work when I test it on the command window.
Anyone knows what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Does is work for the 1x1 identity matrix? 2) Does it work for the $n\times n$ identity matrix?

Comment: Yes it works for identity matrices, but not for every positive definite matrix, like it should

Comment: Isn't eps machine epsilon in Matlab?  You can't expect the residual to be that small.

Comment: What is the simplest matrix you can make this program fail with?

Comment: It fails with A=[3,2;0,3] for instance

Comment: @karlabos CG is not guaranteed to work (besides other special classes of matrices) for matrices which are not *symmetric positive (semi)definite*.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is that eps is machine epsilon in Matlab, and you can't expect the residual to be that small.  You could try introducing a variable $\text{epsilon} = 10^{-8}$ or something, and using that instead of eps.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that eps was pre-defined, I was using as a function of eps... I changed all the instances to epsilon instead, but it still doesn't work...